# Android with spring file uploading MissingServletRequestParameterException

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I want to upload image from android to spring controller.

My problem is i am not able to upload files,i got error in spring controller

My android code is:

```
 public String uploadImageToServer(final UserMO userMO,final Context context,final File profileImage) {
    final String jsonUserMo = gson.toJson(userMO);
    final StringBuilder contactLists = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
    try {
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        FileBody profileFile = new FileBody(profileImage);
        builder.addPart("uploadImg", profileFile);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userMO", jsonUserMo));
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constants.ROOTURL+"/media/uploadUserImage");
        String BOUNDARY= "--ringee--";
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+BOUNDARY);
        post.setEntity(builder.build());
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        Log.i("Ringee",post.toString());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        contactLists.append(rd.readLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contactLists.toString();
}
```

My spring controller code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/uploadUserImage" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadUserImage(@RequestParam(value = "uploadImg") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("userMO") String userBO, HttpSession session,MultipartRequest multipartRequest, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    log.info("hitting image");
    UserBO userBo = gson.fromJson(userBO, UserBO.class);
    // jboss file location to store images
    String filePath = httpServletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "\\resources\\userImages\\" + userBo.getRingeeUserId() + ".png";
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    try {
        if (!file.isEmpty() && file.getBytes().length >= 5242880) {
        log.info("file size is "+file.getBytes());
        }
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()));
            BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            // resizedImage = originalImage.getSubimage(x1, y1, w, h);
            File destination = new File(filePath);
            // save cropped image
            ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "jpeg", destination);
        }
    } catch (Exception Exp) {
        log.info("Upload image failure");
    }
    return "ok";
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]:
org.springframework.web.ind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
Required MultipartFile parameter 'uploadImg' is not present
```

How to solve this problem please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Please update code:

```
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        builder.addPart("uploadImg", new FileBody(profileImage));
        builder.addPart("userMO",new StringBody(jsonUserMo, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constants.ROOTURL+"/media/uploadUserImage");
        post.setEntity(builder.build());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post)
```